# Extracting text using Xpath

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

I am trying to extract the text after an element using Selenium C#.

I have figured out the XPath to use to locate the text using XPath Checker.

```
//*[@id='selectedEciId_5555555']/../following-sibling::text()[1]
```

Using the above returns : " 5555555 (Customer 5 Name)" in XPath Checker.

I have tried the following code to extract the text " 5555555 (Customer 5 Name)" into a variable using the following line of code.

```
var customer = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*@id='selectedEciId_2217611']/../following-sibling::text()[1]")).Text;
```

but receive an error stating "Argument 1 of Window.getComputedStyle does not implement interface Element."

Would someone be able to assist with the correct code to extract the text?

HTML Code copied below for reference:

```
        <label id="iCheck-txcdyh" for="selectedEciId_1111111" class="ibm-access"></label>
        <div aria-disabled="false" aria-checked="false" style="position: relative;" class="iradio_square-blue" role="radio" aria-labelledby="iCheck-txcdyh"><input style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border: 0px none; opacity: 0;" name="selectedCompanyId" id="selectedEciId_1111111" value="1111111" type="radio"><ins style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border: 0px none; opacity: 0;" class="iCheck-helper"></ins></div>&nbsp;1111111&nbsp;(Customer 1 Name)<br>

        <label id="iCheck-x44hah" for="selectedEciId_2222222" class="ibm-access"></label>
        <div aria-disabled="false" aria-checked="false" style="position: relative;" class="iradio_square-blue" role="radio" aria-labelledby="iCheck-x44hah"><input style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border: 0px none; opacity: 0;" name="selectedCompanyId" id="selectedEciId_2222222" value="2222222" type="radio"><ins style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border: 0px none; opacity: 0;" class="iCheck-helper"></ins></div>&nbsp;2222222&nbsp;(Customer 2 Name)<br>

        <label id="iCheck-vljexv" for="selectedEciId_3333333" class="ibm-access"></label>
        <div aria-disabled="false" aria-checked="false" style="position: relative;" class="iradio_square-blue" role="radio" aria-labelledby="iCheck-vljexv"><input style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border: 0px none; opacity: 0;" name="selectedCompanyId" id="selectedEciId_3333333" value="3333333" type="radio"><ins style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border: 0px none; opacity: 0;" class="iCheck-helper"></ins></div>&nbsp;3333333&nbsp;(Customer 3 Name)<br>

        <label id="iCheck-k4wo8e" for="selectedEciId_4444444" class="ibm-access"></label>
        <div aria-disabled="false" aria-checked="false" style="position: relative;" class="iradio_square-blue" role="radio" aria-labelledby="iCheck-k4wo8e"><input style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border: 0px none; opacity: 0;" name="selectedCompanyId" id="selectedEciId_4444444" value="4444444" type="radio"><ins style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border: 0px none; opacity: 0;" class="iCheck-helper"></ins></div>&nbsp;4444444&nbsp;(Customer 4 Name)<br>

        <label id="iCheck-zf06hv" for="selectedEciId_5555555" class="ibm-access"></label>
        <div aria-disabled="false" aria-checked="false" style="position: relative;" class="iradio_square-blue" role="radio" aria-labelledby="iCheck-zf06hv"><input style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border: 0px none; opacity: 0;" name="selectedCompanyId" id="selectedEciId_5555555" value="5555555" type="radio"><ins style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border: 0px none; opacity: 0;" class="iCheck-helper"></ins></div>&nbsp;5555555&nbsp;(Customer 5 Name)<br>

        <label id="iCheck-d9oyt0" for="selectedEciId_6666666" class="ibm-access"></label>
        <div aria-disabled="false" aria-checked="false" style="position: relative;" class="iradio_square-blue" role="radio" aria-labelledby="iCheck-d9oyt0"><input style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border: 0px none; opacity: 0;" name="selectedCompanyId" id="selectedEciId_6666666" value="6666666" type="radio"><ins style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border: 0px none; opacity: 0;" class="iCheck-helper"></ins></div>&nbsp;6666666&nbsp;(Customer 6 Name)<br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the error is occurring when Selenium is trying to check for the visibilty of the element before getting the text.

One solution can be to get the text using the javascript

```
var script = @"return arguments[0].nodeValue;";

var element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*@id='selectedEciId_1111111']/../following-sibling::text()[1]"));

IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
elementText = js.ExecuteScript(script, element).ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly after adding cast to string. string customer = (string) js.ExecuteScript(script, element);

Comment: No worries @RobertBelknap. I have updated the answer to convert the object to string. It would better to have bit more error handling too.